# Hijack Back Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project for a client and I wanted to hijack the browser's back button to navigate backwards through a javascript interface.  I remember using w3schools.com frequently when I started learning javascript, and if you change anything in their preview/testing panel and resubmit, clicking the back button will take you back to the state the window was in last time you clicked the submit button.

I just picked a random page so you could see what I mean:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_sort
```

Just click submit a few times then hit the back button on your browser a few times.

How can I go about this?  I'm sorry if it's a common question, but I've looked all over and just can't seem to track the solution down.

Comment: I actually would like to know how to do this as well.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

Comment: Off-topic: w3schools sucks, see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web) is much better.

Comment: I don't use it anymore except for a quick syntax check once in a while, and agree that MDN is much more comprehensive.